# Python Reading a Web CSV - UnicodeDecodeError: utf-8 into CSV

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, python-requests

When accessing this aws CSV, I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 19: invalid start byte
```

Is ignoring this error acceptable, considering it appears to print all rows in the following code (below). Moreover, how do I convert the printed rows into a pandas dataframe? Thanks.

```
import requests
from contextlib import closing
import csv

url = "http://google.com/MLI/data/devicefailure2.csv"

with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as r:
    f = (line.decode('utf-8') for line in r.iter_lines())
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try directly reading csv

```
pd.read_csv('file', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

or `encoding = "utf-8"` will solve the problem